# How to include a search form in an existing page in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a function called `search` in `views.py` which I use to process search parameters and display results on a different page. My search form is on the home page template so that I can search from there  and be redirected to the page specified by my search function. Currently my `views.py` looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from core.models import Movie
from core.documents import MovieDocument


class MovieList(ListView):
    model = Movie   
    template_name='movie_list.html' 
    paginate_by = 10
    queryset = Movie.objects.all() 


def search(request):

    q = request.GET.get('q')

    if q:
        movies = MovieDocument.search().query("match", title=q)
    else:
        movies = ''

    return render(request, 'search.html', {'movies': movies})
```

The home page is being served by the `MovieList` class and I have the following html snippet for the search field in the home page movie_list.html:

```
<form method="get" action="{{ views.search}}">
<input id="q" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

The url path for MovieList looks like this:
`path('movies',views.MovieList.as_view(),name='MovieList')`

When,for example I type 'terminator' in the search box, the url in the browser changes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies?q=terminator` but the search function is not called and nothing happens. How can I get this working properly, preferably without having to define a new url to capture the search query string but by specifying the search function in the form's `action` attribute, unless that's not possible? Having  the search box on its own page and creating its own url path actually works but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally figured this out, quite simple. All I had to do was add a path for redirecting the search to a new page:

`path('search',views.search,name='search')`

Then I updated the form tag:
`<form method="get" action="{% url 'search' %}">`

It doesn't matter what the names are in the path arguments as long as you are pointing to the correct view function and the form's action is matched to the correct url name.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add views.search directly in form action.

Update your view like this:

```
class MovieList(ListView):
    model = Movie   
    template_name='movie_list.html' 
    paginate_by = 10
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    show_search = False

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.show_search == True:
            template_name='search.html'
        else:
            template_name='movie_list.html'
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return self.render_to_response(context)
    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            q = self.kwargs['q']
        except:
            q = ''
        if (q != ''):
            object_list = self.model.search().query("match", title=q)
            self.show_search = True
        else:
            self.show_search = False
            object_list = self.model.objects.all()
        return object_list
```

Comment: I've removed the action and updated the code but still nothing happens

Comment: Yes my MovieList class looks exactly like yours now.

Comment: Also, can I ask this,  does  `q = self.kwargs['q']` and `q=self.request.GET.get('q')` achieve the same thing, or is the latter for functions only without self?

Comment: And hows the class view going to know how to render the search result to a different page since you haven't included the render part for the search?

Comment: You can override `render_to_response()` to render different page.

Comment: Now I get a `ValueError: The view core.views.MovieList didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` Not sure why django makes it so hard to implement something so simple

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I still got an error here with your last update: `AttributeError: 'MovieList' object has no attribute 'object_list` Anyways I've managed to find an answer and have posted above. Thanks